# Pino can't connect to twitter

Tags: twitter, fedora-13

On a fresh installation of Fedora 13, I tried using Pino to access my twitter account, but Pino always times out even though I'm positive user and password are correct.

When started from the console, Pino gives these error messages:

```
** (pino:5618): WARNING **: Invalid GValue unboxing (wrong type or NULL)

** (pino:5618): WARNING **: re_tweet.vala:202: enchant error for language: en_US

** (pino:5618): WARNING **: re_tweet.vala:204: enchant error for language: en_US.utf8

** (pino:5618): WARNING **: Invalid GValue unboxing (wrong type or NULL)
```

Is that a bug, or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version are you using ? 0.2. doesn't have support for oAuth, which explains the error messages. Try the 0.3 version http://pino-app.appspot.com/

Comment: Yeah, that's version 0.2.11. Since I can't use it with twitter, how is it any good to ship with a distro?

Comment: Well Fedora 13 was released before twitter switched over to oAuth.